# How can I search for stored procedures executing other stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a list of about 350 stored procedures like this:

```
usp_SP1,
usp_SP2
...
```

I want to search through each one looking to see if any of them call other stored procedures or other databases?

I guess I would look for a line like 'exec something' in each one or a specific name of a database. ex. some_other_database

How would I do this to give me a list of the stored procedures that call other stored procedures or contain some specific string? ex. "some other database name"

I can run this below but it finds just the text. is there any way I can ensure it's a exec call and not just text?

```
USE [Your_DB];
GO

SELECT 
    ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE 
    ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%exec %' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
    AND ROUTINE_NAME IN ('usp_SP1', 'usp_SP2')
GO
```

Comment: SQL Server 2000? 2017? Something in between?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the [sys.sql_dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view, like this:

```
SELECT o1.name AS CallerSP, o2.name AS CalledSP
FROM sys.sql_dependencies sd
INNER JOIN sys.objects o1 ON o1.object_id = sd.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o2 ON o2.object_id = sd.referenced_major_id
WHERE o1.type='P' AND o2.type='P'
```

You may need to call [sp_refreshsqlmodule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for all objects before executing this query, if the called SP was created after the caller.

Other options could be to query the [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view or the [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Comment: Keep in mind this only identifies callees in the same database, and it will ignore any calls generated with dynamic SQL or routed through a synonym. Finding references is hard.

Comment: Is there a way I can pass in a list here to just search that list of stored procedures?

Comment: Yes, you can add something like `AND o2.name IN ('proc1','proc2','proc3')`

Answer (score 0):

Not to compete, Razvan Socol is correct. Adding the ways to do it in earlier version back to 2000. All the old tables and views are still query-able even if not visible in ssms.

```
select distinct /* I believe the sys.sys views were added in 2012 or so, still works in 2017  */
     od.name caller_procedure_name
    ,o.name called_procedure_name
from sys.sysdepends d
inner join sys.sysobjects o on o.id = d.depid and o.type = 'P'
inner join sys.sysobjects od on od.id = d.id and od.type = 'P'

select distinct /* should work all the way back to sql 2000, still works in 2017 */
     od.name caller_procedure_name
    ,o.name called_procedure_name
from dbo.sysdepends d
inner join dbo.sysobjects o on o.id = d.depid and o.type = 'P'
inner join dbo.sysobjects od on od.id = d.id and od.type = 'P'
```